# Flutter check if variable is NaN

Tags: dart, flutter

I have `var number;` and it gets assigned by some calculations.

If I do `print(number);` I get `NaN` as response;

I expected that I would be able to do something like

```
if (number is NaN)
```

But I get NaN is not defined.
How to check if variable is `NaN` in flutter?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[NAN](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/double/NAN-constant.html) is a CONSTANT so you can do this

```
if (number == double.nan)
```

also you have this property [isNaN](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/num/isNaN.html) but to use it you must provide the type because it's available only for `num`s so either  `double` or `int`

```
if (number.isNaN)
```

Comment: this is wrong - please check my answer for a complete explanation

Answer (score 14):

You cannot check for nan by comparing it to the double.nan constant. isNan is the way to go.

```
yourNumber.isNaN
```

Why does comparing to double.nan not work?

```dart
print(double.nan == double.nan);
// prints false
print(double.nan.isNaN);
// prints true
```

This is because by definition NaN is not equal to itself. In fact if you would want to implement a NaN check yourself you would do it like so:

```dart
bool isNan(double x) => x != x;
```

This also has the consequence that if you save a NaN into any other kind of  object, the object will no longer be equal to itself (as long as the NaN is used in the comparison - like with data classes). This can lead to unexpected behavior. You could use this code to check for this case.

```
bool hasNan(Object? x) => x != x;
```

In general this is true for all languages i am aware of - not just dart - as it's a hardware thing.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (!number.isNaN) print(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

`num` types have an `isNaN` property, or you can see if the var is equal to `double.nan`. You should define the variable using `num` instead of `var`.

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/num-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Use isFinite property
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/isFinite.html

```
value.isFinite
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use (number.isNaN) condition instead

Comment: This has already been mentioned in some other answers.